# How Do I Center the Facebook Login Button?

Tags: html, facebook

I'm just trying to do a simple test and center the facebook button.  My initial thought is I just need to center the div tag.  However, I've tried everything I can think of like text-align, using css margin: auto, nothing seems to be working.

How do I center the facebook login button to the center of my html page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;

  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9&appId=x";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }
  (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" 
   data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" 
   data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

edit:  added screenshot

[image: description]

Comment: Do you have any CSS? And are you attempting to use JQuery? Because something looks wrong with that function...

Comment: your js doesn't do anything on your html page.  Provide a snippet that shows the problem

Comment: I removed the app string id.  If you add a new app in facebook it'll create you the script you need to include  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the most simple example:

```css
#center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="center">
      <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false">Hello</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I tried, but it doesn't center.  I added the CSS to the HEAD tag as well.  If I make a new div under that one with the id center and something simple like "hello" it centers, but not the facebook login button div tag.

Comment: @thecodingmate I've edited my answer. You need to wrap the login button with a div with the id of 'center', and not the login button itself.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I have an answer that works.  I ended up wrapping the inside div with an outside div that's centered and that seems to work.  So something like

```
<div id="center">
    <div ...
</div>
```

And, of course, adding the appropriate CSS listed above.

Comment: Check the edit time.  His solution did not work before I answered my question and then he changed.  I accepted his solution out of courtesy when he made the edit.